# Recursive method in a linked list

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently learning about recursion and how I can implement it within my code. I am trying to write a **recursive** method **replace** which takes a given String and replaces **every** occurrence of the item with the new item.

Any insight would be highly appreciated, and thanks for your time.

```
    package lib;

    public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList(Node h){
        head = h;
    }
    public Node getHead(){
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead(Node n){
        head = n;
    }
    public void insertAfter(Node newNode, Node prev){
        if (newNode != null){
                newNode.setNext(prev.next());
        }
        prev.setNext(newNode);
    }
    public void insertFront(Node newNode){


        this.setHead(newNode);
    }

    public void deleteAfter(Node prev){
        if (prev.next() == null){

        } else{
        prev.setNext(prev.next().next());
        }
    }

    public void replace (String item, String newItem, Node n) {

    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = "";
        if (head != null){
            Node current = head;
            do {
                str = str + current.getItem();
                current = current.next();
                if (current != head && current != null){
                    str = str + ", ";
                }
            } while(current != head && current != null);
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small error with insertFront.

```
public void insertFront(Node newNode) {
    newNode.setNext(head);
    this.setHead(newNode);
}
```

Recursion means doing a bit of work, and for the *other* rest call the function recursively.

```
public void replace (String item, String newItem, Node n) {
    if (n != null) {
        n.data = n.data.replace(item, newItem); // String.replace
        replace(item, newItem, n.next()); // Recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there thanks a lot for your solution. However when i edit the insertFront method to your solution i get a syntax error thats says ''Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 next cannot be resolved or is not a field

 at lib.LinkedList.insertFront(LinkedList.java:22)
 at main.ListApp.main(ListApp.java:30) '' 

The suggested solution is to create field 'next' in type 'Node'

Comment: Sorry, I did not try to really find the correct method/field. Corrected the code.

Comment: THANK YOU! ever so much.

Comment: If possible could you please do the same for the recursion question as i am having a similar issue. Once again Thanks.

Comment: I did not see how to get and set data; maybe `setData(...getData() ...)`. Do not be deterred by code.

Comment: The only info that i have been provided with is
'public void replace (String item, String newItem, Node n) {
//Add code here.
}'

With this i need to write a **recursive** method **replace** which takes a given String and replaces **every** occurrence of the item with the given new item.

Comment: That is exactly done: if there is no node (null) we are done. Otherwise do a string replacement on n.data (replacing multiple occurrences), after that recurse on the rest of the list.

Comment: Please find the nodes below.

 
public static void main(String[] args){
  Node n4 = new Node("green", null);
  Node n3 = new Node("orange", n4);
  Node n2 = new Node("blue", n3);
  Node n1 = new Node("red", n2);
'

Comment: Call `linkedList.replace("e", "E", linkedList.getHead());` - Sorry I have to work now, good luck

Comment: No worries, Thanks for your valuable time.